# PayPal PreApproved Payments

Tags: paypal, payment

I am using PayPal PreApproved payments for my crowd funding website, where project backers are only charged if the project is successfully backed.

I am worried that high rate of payments will fail when the PayPal API tries to collect the funds when a project is successful:

- a backer might not have any funds in their PayPal account
- a backer might close their account once the project is successful (to intentionally stop payment)
- a backer might remove/cancel their preapproved payment
- etc...

There are a number of ways that the payment could fail which would mean that the project owner would not get their funds.

Can anyone suggest a way of tightening or securing payments. Please note, that PayPal will only allow you to use PreApproved payments for crowdfunding. Please also note that project owners need to be able to receive the funds from my site. Sometimes, these funds can be as small as $10 or up to $10,000 so we need to use PayPal to pay them as there is not other method of getting the funds to the project owner

Answer (score 8):

I've implemented Paypal Adaptive payments and used them for payments at http://www.wethetrees.com and we had the exact problems you are describing. The capture rate is almost random, we were down to 35% with one campaign and had to manually send all backers invoices.

When capturing we had backers with closed/unauthorized accounts, insufficient funds, unavailable payment methods etc. We switched to just doing direct capture for a while, which is great since we get 100% of all pledges, but Paypal closed our account without notice when one of our campaigns mentioned the word "Cuba".

The solution in the end was to scrap Paypal so now we're using Wepay and Dwolla, and we're considering Bitpay (Bitcoin) as well. Seems to like Paypal wants to kill crowdfunding or doesn't understand it. Anything less than a 90% capture rate is totally unacceptable and will cause projects to fail.

Comment: Sounds to me like your crowd didn't really want to fund your project, otherwise they'd make sure they have funds available.  I personally  haven't run into the issues you've described here.  I mean, it does happen sometimes, but no where near the fail rate you're talking about.

Comment: It happened on nearly all our projects during 6 months. I think only 3 out of 35 projects had a 100% capture rate using Paypal Adaptive Payments. How can you do crowdfunding when you can't guarantee the funds?

Also, the bigger the contribution, the higher the chance that the funds are not available. We once couldn't capture a $2000 contribution when the project goal was $5000. Pretty lame.

Comment: So did you contact the person and ask them why they agreed to contribute $2k but then when you went to take the payment the funds weren't available, or did you just give up at that point?  Maybe they never added their bank account or credit card to their PayPal account.

Comment: Yeah we contacted them, but the point is that if this is even remotely possible then Paypal Adaptive Payments doesn't work for crowdfunding. Funds *must* be guaranteed. Crowdfunding campaigns can last several months, so you really need guarantees. If you have many campaigns running, it's very time consuming and annoying to ask people to pay again. Anyway, refunds are free within 60 days, so I really don't see the point of using Paypal Adaptive Payments. We're super happy right now, not a single issue with payments since we scrapped paypal. I don't recommend Paypal Adaptive Payments at all.

Answer (score 4):

Preapproval isn't the only thing they'll allow you to use.  That's just one part of the [Adaptive Payments API](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_adaptivepayments.pdf), but you could go with a [delayed chained payment](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/how-to/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc), too.

This way your account can be treated sort of like an Escrow.  You can use the [Pay API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation) to create payments in the system that are split between receivers accordingly.  Only the primary receiver would get paid at first, though, and then you can call ExecutePayment to submit the secondary payments from the primary account within 90 days.

This way the primary account holds all of the funds so they're available to pay out when the goal is reached.  If the goal is not reached the payments could be refunded.

Comment: I know that, but does that solve the problems mentioned in my post? A backer would pay me the platform fee but then later when I try to execute the payment and send it to the campaign owner there is no guarantee that the money will be available, just like with preapprovals, right?