# Bundling of small payments with guaranteed execution

Tags: google-app-engine, mobile, paypal, in-app-purchase, payment

I´m working on a service where users will have several purchases (each ranging from ~5€ to ~20€) over the course of a few hours within an app. 
Instead of processing each payment individually with fees occurring each time I would like to **bundle** those and execute them together (let´s say after 6 hours).
The apps will be for Android and iOS with the backend on Google App Engine.

The Paypal Preapproval feature sounds in theory like what I want. But this thread [PayPal PreApproved Payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934811/paypal-preapproved-payments) makes me think that the risk is high that many of the **payments will fail**?

Is there a solution around which actually guarantees, that the payments will happen in the end?

I would be open to other services than PayPal as long as it is easy for the user, has affordable fees and guarantees that the payment will occur in full.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Preapproval" means you are collecting the user's approval for future payments rather than getting their agreement with each payment; you are correct that this does not guarantee their ability to pay. Someone can agree to be billed but not be able to pay the amount they are later billed.

You can get a "soft" check of their ability to pay in some PayPal APIs (depends which specific PayPal product you are using), but without a guarantee. This soft check simply says "if I were to ask you right now for $10, would you probably be able to pay it?" Useful, and has ZERO impact to the customer: no additional UI for them; they won't see the amount; and they will see nothing in their account after the check. This will reduce your risk but not eliminate it. Suitable for cases where you are willing to take a low-single-digit failure % and either forgo those sales or follow up with the customers whose payments go bump.

If you need to guarantee that funds are available, and hold those funds against future purchases, you must collect an "authorization" from your buyer. An authorization places a hold on funds in the buyer's account. This means that a) you must know how much to request, and b) the buyer must see and approve the authorization transaction (unless you previously collected preauthorization agreement) and c) the authorization visibly holds funds in their account after they approve it.

This is basically the same for credit/debit cards and PayPal, although the details differ a bit.

A single authorization can, with some limitations, be used to complete multiple separate purchases, although in this case fees will be charged for each resulting payment. Or you can track how much liability a customer is actually stacking up and make one bundled capture (aka payment) at the end, thus potentially slightly reducing your fees. (With PayPal at least you would pay the per-transaction component of the fee only once, and the % would be the same. With other processors, using authorizations this way usually carries an additional auth charge plus exposes you to escalating fees when/if the total amount captured is not exactly equal to the amount authorized or based on the elapsed time between authorization and capture. It's very complicated and can be hard to determine when or if you will actually save any money.)

One other difference between PayPal and other processors: there are a few edge cases where PayPal will decline captures even after you authorize. PayPal only guarantees you a limited amount of overage. So if you authorize for $10 and capture for $12 you are OK, but if you authorize for $10 and capture for $100 PayPal will complete that for you if the buyer can, but is NOT guaranteeing success. And no security is perfect, and if for example PayPal happens to discover *between the time of the auth and the time of the capture* that the sending account has been compromised (stolen), they will freeze it and decline your capture. This is a vanishingly small %, but it CAN happen. So it's a 99.9% guarantee, but technically not 100%. (A credit card company NEVER fails a capture operation, so in this case would complete your capture... but likely send you a chargeback to take the money back from you later.)

Comment: Geewiz, thanks a lot for your great effort! So you would propose Paypal as a good solution for my usecase? As I said, the time between the preapproval and the payment will only be several hours - so the failure rate should be rather low, correct? Then I could add up the payments in the backend and either process them in significant chunks (lets say always when reaching 50€ to reduce the risk of a big missed payment) or when the time has past.
What do you think about Dwolla or Wepay for my case, if you have insights to those services.

Comment: Yes, this is a common use case that PayPal supports well; it is a solid choice IMO. You just need to decide whether to take the user impact of placing authorizations (holds) or live with the small % fallout of not having the funds reserved. I have not used dwolla or wepay and thus cannot comment on those, other than saying that the PayPal user base is MUCH wider than other account-based/wallet-based systems.