# Making a payment later with PayPal REST APIs

Tags: paypal, payment

I'm trying to use PayPal REST APIs instead of Classic APIs for forward compatibility. What I want to do is to save user details and make a payment later. The point of making a payment could be several months later. [It seems it's possible with the Class APIs, though it looks not perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934811/paypal-preapproved-payments).

However, I cannot find how to do that with REST APIs. It seems not possible, but I want to check if I missed something.

These what I found.

- [I can make an order and capture it later, but an order is valid only for 29 days](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-process-order/#execute-the-order).
- [I can make a recurring charge with billing plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/), but the point of making a payment is undefined in my case.
- [I can save user's credit card detail in the Vault and use it later](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/), but I don't want to make users put their credit card details.

So, in this case should I use the Class APIs?

Comment: Interesting. I think one item that needs to be clarified, including in that link on crowdfunding is the term "guaranteed funds". No matter how one cuts it, that term essentially means someone has to be "charged" some amount (or funds "freezed") to cover that "guarantee". That's probably going to run afoul of Banks (at the end of the day, its banking/credit card rules).